# Add Component using Delphi/Pascal to C++ Builder?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I noticed the components for C++ Builder seem to have been built using Delphi/Pascal.  I wanted some type of MRU component for C++ Builder and found this: [TMRU Componet](https://www.cnblogs.com/shangdawei/archive/2013/05/05/3060793.html) but it's in Delphi/Pascal.

How can I build this and add it to the available components on the Palette when I don't have Delphi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++Builder includes a Delphi compiler.  You can add Delphi `.pas` files to C++Builder projects, and when compiled they will generate `.hpp` files that you can `#include` in your C++ code.

Alternatively, that MRU code is not very large, you could just translate it from Pascal into C++ and then use it in a normal `.cpp`/`.h` unit.

Comment: I added it and sure enough it created the .hpp file, I then added the .hpp file as well then added a #include "uMRU.hpp" to the main form .h file.  However, how do I get it to show up in the palette so I can use it?

Comment: To use a component in the IDE, you have to 1) compile the component's source as a separate `.BPL` package that exports a [`Register()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declaring_the_Register_Procedure) function which calls [`RegisterComponents()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.RegisterComponents), and then 2) install the `.BPL` into the IDE so the component is available for use in other projects. Read the documentation: [Making Components Available at Design Time](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Making_Components_Available_at_Design_Time)

Comment: Otherwise, don't install the component into the IDE at all, just create it dynamically in your UI code at runtime. Especially since the component in question is not a visual component to begin with, and it has very few `published` properties to appear in the Object Inspector, so making it available in the IDE's Form Designer is not necessary in order to use it.

Comment: I see - Is it standard practice to instantiate the object in the forms constructor or in the OnCreate event?   how about cleanup, is it standard practice to delete the object in the destructor, OnDestroy or just leave it for automatic clean up?

Comment: I wonder if they have something better than OnDestroy as well since WM_ENDSESSION doesn't end up calling that.

Comment: @user3161924 DO NOT use the `OnCreate` event in C++, as it is a Delphi idiom that *can* invoke *undefined behavior* in C++. Use the Form's constructor instead. You don't need to destroy the component manually at all if you assign an `Owner` to it, like the Form.